# Remove profile field description

Tags: php, custom-fields, buddypress

i have added a `custom field` in user profile.It's Optional for admin to let users see this field from back end.Problem is when admin removes this `field`,its description still shows.Is there any way to remove this when we remove this `field`?

thanks :)

Comment: can you post some code, which will describe your problem?

Comment: another way, is there any way to remove field description with out removing the input field? 'This field can be seen by: Everyone Change'

Comment: it's very hard to help you, if I don't know, how the field description is showed and how your "remove" algorithm working

Comment: I'm really sorry for my english sir.whenever i remove a custom field,the field description still shows there like "This field can be seen by: Everyone Change". so is there any way to remove this ? like any buddypress action/filter? thank you for quick reply.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a flag like 'show' as radio button in the backend and let the admin set it. If the flag is set then only show it on front end else dont.

Comment: At back end admin have a check box.I'm doing like if(checkbox value == yes){     $fields['field_name'] = 'function_name_here';
}so in this way , field vanishes but 'This field can be seen by: Everyone Change' keeps showing. thanks for the help :)

Comment: can you please put your code here so that i can help you in a better way.